# How do I get the current filter for a crossfilter dimension?

Tags: crossfilter

I have a `crossfilter.dimension`.  How do I get the current filter set on it (for example if it was set by a brush from a chart)?

Example:

```
dimension.filterRange([1,15]) // returns dimension
```

Given this filtered dimension, how do I get the values 1 and 15 out?

Comment: I don't believe you can. It would be nice to be able to access both dimension accessors and current filters, but I can see why they don't allow this. The workaround is to track the filter separately so that you can look it up when you need to.

Answer (score 2):

Stumbled on this old question because it is the top-voted unanswered crossfilter question, with 1k views!

This feature was contributed by Thomas Gillet in [1.4.5](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/releases/tag/1.4.5) as [dimension.currentFilter()](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_currentFilter)

The tough remaining problem: when you get beyond [filterExact](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_filterExact) and [filterRange](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_filterRange), the more complex filters use [filterFunction](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_filterFunction). You might be able to retrieve the function but functions are essentially opaque.

For example, if you are using dc.js, it will generate a filter function when

- multiple items are selected in pie chart, row chart, or bar chart with ordinal dimension
- the chart has a two-dimensional filter, like the scatter plot or the heatmap

For this reason, if you're using dc.js, you should use [chart.filters()](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/BaseMixin.html#filters__anchor) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Gordon.  This was really helpful to me!  One note - your link is correct -- it goes to filters(), but the text displays as chart.filter() which is in the API, but doesn't return multiple filters on a chart.  I tried to edit your answer, but it won't allow single character changes!

Comment: Thanks @sottitron. Didn't see this earlier because you added an answer instead of commenting on my answer. Fixed now, please delete this.